# Using Gradle `from project` in `settings.gradle` for a module in the same level of folder cannot be found

Tags: gradle

In https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:importing-published-catalog, when we want to include a versionCatalog from another library, in our `settings.gradle`, we can use

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            from("com.mycompany:catalog:1.0")
        }
    }
}
```

If the `catalog` is in the same project, I tried to do as below

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            from project(":catalog")
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps complaining that `Project with path ':catalog' could not be found.` even though the `catalog` project is there in the same level as `settings.gradle`.

How can I solve the problem?